# Parameter Names not showing up on event page in GA4 reports

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

[events in last 30 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Eov.png)

[reports > engagement > events > add_to_cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFnwn.png)

I've had this problem for awhile across multiple GA4 setups:

In the Realtime view and Debugview I can see the event parameter names and values just fine but on the event page in the reports it only shows the parameter values and not the parameter names.

Anyone know what's going on here? I thought it was a bug on Google's end that would get fixed but it's been months now.

[GTM tag setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foeve.png)

[custom dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7MAe.png)

This is my tag setup in GTM. I tried to put user properties to see if anything would change (unlikely I know) and sure enough it didn't make a difference. I also added custom dimensions in GA4 since a lot of people were saying this fixed it for them but unfortunately this didn't fix it in my case.